# Remove a response when reacting with an ❌

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I tried doing this and adapting it from discordjs.guide, but I've either adapted something wrongly or it isn't working in my context. I tried this:

```
botMessage.react('❌');

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
};

botMessage.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
    const reaction = collected.first();

    console.log('a')

    if(reaction.emoji.name === '❌'){
        console.log('x')

        botMessage.delete(1);
    }
}).catch(collected => {});
```

`botMessage` is the response from the bot, since I am using a message command.
neither of the `console.log()` output anything.

any help is grateful and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is add the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent:

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS /* other intents */] });
```

Comment: thanks lol its always the simple stuff i forget